# Disable MFMT in lftp

Tags: lftp

How to disable MFMT in `lftp`?

I use `lftp` mirror command to sync my files with the remote server.
Looks like `lftp` send `MFMT` command after uploading file.
This is undesirable in my case and I would like to turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set ftp:use-feat off
```

Lftp won't use FEAT to find out existing server features and thus won't use the MFMT command.

Comment: Thanks I will try.